# ADR volume and stock price

Tags: trading, adr

If a stock is listed on the Frankfurt Stock Exchange and also on the NYSE, does trading on the NYSE (after the FRA is closed) impact the price of the stock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The relationship is not always linear but there won't be big differences because that will create an opportunity for price arbitrage. When doing comparisons, don't forget to adjust for currency.